# PC turning off intermittently

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, hardware-failure

**Current Specs**:

```
Motherboard: Maximus VII Hero (Socket 1150)
Processor:   Intel Core i7-4790K
Ram:         32GB (4x8GB) DDR3-1599
Video:       EVGA GTX 1070
PSU:         EVGA 750 G3
SSD:         Samsung 850 Pro 512GB
OS:          Windows 10 Pro x64
```

**Problem**:

While the computer is in use I intermittently get a power failure that appears to be hardware related. When it occurs the computer simply shuts off. There is no shutdown. It's as if the plug has been pulled.

The event log records the occurrence of a sudden loss of power but there are no details or errors/warnings preceding the event that indicate a root cause.

This problem does not occur if the computer is not in use. For example, I left the computer on for 14 days with a slight GPU load (mining cryptocurrency) without any human interaction. The issue did not surface. Then I used the computer for a few hours this morning and the problem occurred again.

**Steps Taken**:

1. Replaced PSU (*no effect*)
2. Replaced GPU (*no effect*)
3. Disconnected all drives but boot drive (*no effect*)
4. Memtest86 (*1.5 pass, no errors*)

   - Pass 1, no errors (considering the frequency with which I experience this issue my expectation is to see errors in the first pass or not at all)
5. Update BIOS, clear CMOS (*no effect*)
6. Spinrite on boot drive (*system halted -- bought replacement SSD*)
7. Boot into Safe Mode with networking (*to do*)

Comment: Did you replace it with a identical PSU? It's possible the GPU is causing the PSU to trip out due to the load?

Comment: The current PSU is a newer version of the old PSU that was in the system. The wattage is the same. It's unlikely that the hardware is drawing more than the total available PSU power. Most estimates put this build at under 400W.

Comment: It's not the total power draw that's the problem, GPU's can have huge power draws, and a PSU which isn't designed for that won't be able to deliver enough on a particular rail to keep your machine up, and the effect is what you're describing.Can you identify the PSU you're using, so we can check what it's delivering on the gpu rail?

Comment: The PSU is: EVGA 750 G3 (https://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=220-G3-0750-X1)

Comment: From [Pierre LAGOUTTE](https://superuser.com/users/857228/pierre-lagoutte): Maybe a temperature sensor is working wrong?  You should install a monitoring software to check.

Answer (score -2):

Have you try booting Windows USB to go stick to know if the issue persist?

Have you try safe mode in windows?

Comment: I'll try safe mode w/ networking after Memtest and Spinrite. I don't have a Windows to go stick -- I could investigate getting a compatible device and creating one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).